# How to display any message after completion of any task

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am using Apex command button to perform certain operation. after completion  of the operation I want to display certain message in popup window.

Can somebody help me on this.

```
<apex:commandButton action="(method name)" 
                    id="<id value>" 
                    oncomplete="showPopUp" 
                    value="<test>" 
                    style="margin-left: 20px;" 
                    rendered="<rendering logic>" />
<script> 
    function showPopUp() { alert("Need to Populate publication Type"); } 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked into using [page messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_message.htm)? They don't pop up in a separate window, but they do provide a useful way to show messages in a visualforce page.

Comment: I already tried with the same, but no popup is displayed, operation completed but no message displayed

<apex:commandButton action="(method name)" id="<id value>" oncomplete="showPopUp" value="<test>" style="margin-left: 20px;" rendered="<rendering logic>" />

<script>
        function showPopUp()
            {
                alert("Need to Populate publication Type");
            }
    </script>

Comment: If you include an `<apex:pageMessages>` tag in you VF page, the messages you add in the controller should be displayed. They don't pop up though. What you have so far looks like it should work if you add `()` after `showPopUp`

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript for this purpose.
Call a javascript method on oncomplete attribute of the commandbutton, and in that javascript function , do alert method.

```
<script>
function showPopup(){
     alert('Operation Completed'); //you can give your message here
}
</script>
```

your command button :

```
<Apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!your method name}" oncomplete="showPopup()"/>
```

Comment: I already tried with the same, but no popup is displayed, operation completed but no message displayed

<apex:commandButton action="(method name)" id="<id value>" oncomplete="showPopUp" value="<test>" style="margin-left: 20px;" rendered="<rendering logic>" />

<script>
        function showPopUp()
            {
                alert("Need to Populate publication Type");
            }
    </script>

Comment: <apex:commandButton action="(method name)" id="<id value>" oncomplete="showPopUp();" value="<test>" style="margin-left: 20px;" rendered="<rendering logic>" /> replace "ShowPopup" with this "ShowPopup()" this is a function call

Answer (score 2):

if u want to display a popup then u can do code like this :

in your apex class save method make boolean variable = true like :

**Apex class :**

```
 public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}
    public void Save() {
            displayPopup = true;
        }
```

and in close method :

```
public void close() {
    displayPopup = false;
}
```

and on **vf page** :

```
<style type="text/css">
       .customPopup{
            background-color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            left: 50%;
            padding:10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: -250px;
            top:100px;
        }
        .hideStyle{ 
            margin-left: 45% !important;
            width: 30px !important; 
        }
    </style>

<apex:commandButton value="Show Pop up" action="{!save}" rerender="popup"/>
<apex:outputPanel id="popup">
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">

                Save successfully !!! <br/><br/><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Close" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="popup" styleClass="hideStyle"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I have to populate my Conformation message after completion of certain operation. So its not possible to put it in Action parameter

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a new field of type Checkbox on the  Account Object say IsSubmittedForApproval. In the Initial Submissions Actions for the Approval Process you can add a Field Update which updates the IsSubmittedForApproval field to TRUE(i.e. checked).

Then I will create a Visualforce Page with following HTML:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <script>
      if(
          "{!Account.Owner}" == "{!$User.Id}" && 
          {!Account.IsSubmittedForApproval__c} != true
      )
          alert('Please Submit the Acount for Approval !');
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Now, I would place this Visualforce Page as an Inline one on the Accounts Page Layout.